# Seflf Join Query

Tags: mysql, self-join

I have a query

```
SELECT * FROM msg where sender = receiver
```

In which sender and receiver are two columns of the msg table.

The query works fine. Now my question is :

Is this a `self join`? I think this is a simple query which compares values from two columns from same table where as in `self join` we join the table to itself to get resultant table with columns of same table twice.

for example : `SELECT * from msg m Join msg p on m.id = p.id`;

can any one clarify?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Why are you in doubt when you have such excellent explanations?

Comment: The only reason I came up with question because http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25773/how-to-write-a-self-join-query-in-drupal-7-using-db-select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   SELECT * FROM msg where sender = receiver
```

is not a self join.

> Self join is just like any other join, except that two 
>       instances of the same table will be joined in the query.

It's quite common when you have a table that references itself. Example: an employee table where every employee can have a manager, and you want to list all employees and the name of their manager.

Comment: If the second para is a quote, give a source for the quote.  If not, it doesn't need to be indented as code (as it was originally) or marked as a quote (as I made it).  It can be a plain sentence.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. I agree with you completely. The only reason I came up with this question is because http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25773/how-to-write-a-self-join-query-in-drupal-7-using-db-select